# Django many to many relation, include all IDs in queryset in both directions

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

I have 2 models connected via M2M relation

```py
class Paper(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(B, related_name='papers')

class Author():
  name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

- Is there a way to include `authors` as all related authors' IDs (and maybe name somehow)?
- Is there a way to include `papers` IDs as reverse relation (and maybe title as well)?

```py
Author.objects.all().annotate(related_papers=F('papers'))
```

this only adds id of one paper, first one it finds I think.

Furthermore, changing `related_papers` to `papers` gives an error:

> ```
> ValueError: The annotation ‘papers’ conflicts with a field on the
> model.
> ```

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want. You can access relationships by just using `your_author.papers.all()` or `your_paper.authors.all()`. It will be already accessible from the `.all()` query, creating the papers field (and thus the error).

Comment: I am trying to return the IDs in django rest framework API.
From what I understand, at papers key a `ManyRelatedManager` is present. does this manager run query only when we access the contents of m2m key?

So does drf run the query on each m2m key for every object? So a query for every item in row? That would get really slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand in your comments, you're using DRF. I will give you 2 answers.

**1)** If you're talking about model serializer, you can use [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) :

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    papers=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name', 'papers']

class PaperSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Paper
        fields = '__all__'
```

This will return the IDs for the other side of the relationship whether you're on Paper or Author side. That will return the primary keys, not a representation of the object itself.

**2)** Now you're also talking about performance (e.g. database hit at each iteration).

Django (not DRF-specific) has a queryset method to handle preloading related objects. It's called [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

For example, if you know you're going to need the relation object attributes and want to avoid re-querying the database, do as follow:

```py
Author.objects.all().prefetch_related('papers') 
# papers will be already loaded, thus won't need another database hit if you iterate over them.
```

Comment: `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and `prefetch_related` together works great! Thanks :) 
`prefetch_related` especially reduced query time from 1.5s to 300ms

Comment: It's a common mistake to annotate or iterate over a queryset. `prefetch_related` (many/one to many) and `select_related` (one/many to one) are both important to know for relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it has already been implemented for you. You should include a Many-to-Many relationship to author in your Paper model like this:

```
class Paper(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
  authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='papers')
```

That gives you the opportunity to add `Author` objects to a related set using
`p.authors.add(u)`, assuming that `p` is the object of `Paper` model, and `a` is an object of `Author` model.

- You can access all related authors of a `Paper` instance using `p.authors.all()`.
- You can access all related papers of an `Author` instance using `u.papers.all()`.

This will return an instance of `QuerySet` that you can operate on.

---

See this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) page to learn more.